# Why smoothScrollTo inside onTouchEvent does not work when I do Scroll?

Tags: android, scrollview, horizontalscrollview, smooth-scrolling

On the next code:

```
hScroll.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                hScroll.smoothScrollTo(20, 0);
            }
            return false;
        }
}
```

When I only touch the `HorizontalScrollView`it works, but if I move the scroll it doesn't. Someone can help me? (Sorry for my poor English)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you touch , it includes two actions , MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN and MotionEvent.ACTION_UP. If you want the same result when scrolling, you should change like this

```
if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP || event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
    hScroll.smoothScrollTo(20, 0);
}
```